# How to initiate ValueNotifier value from Future

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I need to initiate my `ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier>` from http result. I have service like this.

```dart
class AddressService {
  Future<Address> getMainAddress() async {
     return await callHttpHere();
  }
}
```

And in my `StatelessWidget`:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context){
  return Scaffold(
    body: ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<Address>>(
      create: (_) => ValueNotifier(IWantInitiateThisFrom_GetMainAddress);
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html):

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<Address> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

        return ChangeNotifierProvider<ValueNotifier<Address>>(
          create: (_) => ValueNotifier(snapshot.data),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
}
```